# How to Validate Checkbox in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox

I am trying to validate my checkbox in a form with different fields, but the problem I am getting is that

HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="login_label">Courses</label>
    <span style="color:#00bfff">*</span>
    <input [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="courses_mba" type="checkbox" class="" value="mba">Mba
    <input [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="courses_btech" type="checkbox" class="" value="btech">Btech
    <input [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="courses_mtech" type="checkbox" class="" value="mtech">Mtech
</div>
```

Ts Code:

```
if (this.jobForm.invalid && (this.courses_mba === undefined || this.courses_btech === undefined || this.courses_mtech === undefined)) {
    this.snackBarService.requiredValue(' Please complete the form');
} else {
    this.job_courses = this.courses_mtech ? 'mtech' : '' + this.courses_btech ? 'btech' : '' + this.courses_mba ? 'mba' : '';
    this.snackBarService.requiredValue(' form Submitted Successfully');
    console.log('CArray', this.job_coursess);
    console.log('Course', this.job_courses);
    console.log('mba', this.courses_mba);
    console.log('mtech', this.courses_btech);
    console.log('btech', this.courses_mtech);
}
```

I am trying to display whose are checked should be display on console by I am not getting the proper output, even the checkbox are not selected the `"job_courses"` is showing the `"btech"` I tried to check by check mba and btech its giving me random value i.e sometime btech sometime mtech.
                 What I am expecting is that what I checked should be display in console.

Comment: Some typos here: `console.log('mtech', this.courses_btech);`
`console.log('btech', this.courses_mtech);` You are writing `"mtech" + courses_btech`, and vice versa.

Comment: here i am just check what is the value of btech, mtech

Comment: Please make a [mcve] showing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have your if condition wrong
for your specific requirement you should check whether form is valid or any of the checkboxes are checked.

```
if ( this.jobForm.invalid ||( this.courses_mba === undefined && this.courses_btech === undefined && this.courses_mtech === undefined) {
    this.snackbarService.requiredValue('Please complete the form');
} else {
    this.job_courses = this.courses_mtech ? 'mtech' : '' + this.courses_btech ? 'btech' : '' + this.courses_mba ? 'mba' : '';
    this.snackBarService.requiredValue(' form Submitted Successfully');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos in your console logs:

```
console.log('mtech', this.courses_btech); 
console.log('btech', this.courses_mtech);
```

Should be

```
console.log('mtech', this.courses_mtech); 
console.log('btech', this.courses_btech);
```

And this line, will only give you the first match of all checkboxes.

```
this.job_courses = this.courses_mtech ? 'mtech' : '' + this.courses_btech ? 'btech' : '' + this.courses_mba ? 'mba' : '';
```

It will only be either `mtech`, or `btech`, or `mba`. If you want it to be more than that, you must change it. It is easier to read if you make three if-else sentences instead. I am now `making job_courses` be a string of all checked answers.

```
this.job_courses = "";
if(this.courses_mtech){
 this.job_courses += "mtech"
}
if(this.courses_btech){
 this.job_courses += "btech"
}
if(this.courses_mba){
 this.job_courses += "mba"
}
```

`console.log(this.job_courses);` Will print "mtechbtechmba" if all three checkboxes are checked. I do not know what the desired output is, so change the code to your liking.

Comment: for now, I want only 3 things(mba,mtech or btech), which I am not getting, I tried above method also but still not get the appropriate result

Answer (score 0):

[(ngModel)] attributes requires **name** attribute too along with it, to work thats what you are missing in your code .

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="login_label">Courses</label>
  <span style="color:#00bfff">*</span>
  <input [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="mba" [(ngModel)]="courses_mba" type="checkbox" class="" value="mba">Mba
  <input [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="btech" [(ngModel)]="courses_btech" type="checkbox" class="" value="btech">Btech
  <input [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="mtech" [(ngModel)]="courses_mtech" type="checkbox" class="" value="mtech">Mtech
</div>
```

Adding it something will like this , will make it work.